# create data table in excel VSTO addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

    var data = new object[11, 2]
    {
        { "Header_Item", "Header_Value"},
        { "Company", 23},
        { "User Group", 25},
        { "Voucher Type", "M"},
        { "Currency", "GBP"},
        { "Accounting Currency", "GBP"},
        { "Curr_Rate", 31},
        { "Parellel Currency", 31},
        { "Parellel Currency Rate", 31},
        { "Text", 31},
        { "Reversing", 31}
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[(i + 1), (j + 1)].Value = data[i, j];

        }
    }
    //var table = activeSheet.Tables.Add("Table1", "A1:B11", true);
}
```

i want to create data table using this *"Header item","Header value"* columns.
I,m using visual studio excel VSTO addins

I found that i can convert this data to table using that commented line, but it gives me error

can you guys help me with this

Comment: See [Export DataTable To Excel in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/exporting-datatable-to-excel-in-C-Sharp-using-interop/)

Comment: i update the question, can you help me to solve that